# Why is my rsync command not working between Openshift gears?

Tags: ssh, openshift, rsync

I'm trying - like many other people - to rsync data between gears of a scalable app.

I have created a minutely cron file that gets executed and can get and parse a list of gears. It can then determine which ones are NOT the local gear and then tries to rsync the app-root/data folder of each gear to the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR (should be on local gear)...

The first part works, but the rsync command fails with:

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]

I have tried about a dozen variants of

> rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}.ssh/id_rsa" $targetgear@app-user.rhcloud.com:app-root/data/test/ ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}test

$targetgear is a variable from parsing the list of gears - it's the long string of "stuff" in the gear name... the script loops through the csv list provided by haproxy and correctly writes what it finds to a log file, so I know it's getting at least that far...

The id_rsa file exists and has been added to the account in the web control panel.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. I have combed pages and pages of forum posts and documentation on rsync and ssh, but can't seem to get around it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a ssh problem? `ssh -i ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}.ssh/id_rsa $targetgear@app-user.rhcloud.com hostname` shows you something?

Comment: THANK YOU RAUL!!!
Ok... The problem was the url for the target gear - I needed the long string of gunk TWICE: 
`$targetgear@$targetgear-user.rhcloud.com` ...

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU RAUL!!!
Ok... The problem was the url for the target gear - I needed the long string of gunk TWICE:

`$targetgear@$targetgear-user.rhcloud.com` ...

and not

`$targetgear@app-user.rhcloud.com`

The app name prefix in the url is replaced by the gear ID.